# Install graphlab-create in Python on Windws 10

Tags: python, graphlab

All -- I see below which means graphlab is already installed (or not)? But help("modules") doesn't show graphlab as one of the installed packages, AND I am unable to run "import graphlab" as it results in "No module named graphlab".

```
(gl-env) C:\Users>pip install graphlab-create
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): graphlab-create in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): decorator==4.0.9 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): psclient in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): tornado==4.3 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests==2.9.1 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): genson==0.1.0 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): certifi==2015.04.28 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jsonschema==2.5.1 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): awscli==1.6.2 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): boto==2.33.0 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): multipledispatch>=0.4.7 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): sseclient==0.0.8 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): prettytable==0.7.2 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from psclient->graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): singledispatch in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from tornado==4.3->graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): backports.ssl-match-hostname in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from tornado==4.3->graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): backports-abc>=0.4 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from tornado==4.3->graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): functools32 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema==2.5.1->graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): colorama==0.2.5 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from awscli==1.6.2->graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): botocore<0.74.0,>=0.73.0 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from awscli==1.6.2->graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docutils>=0.10 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from awscli==1.6.2->graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): bcdoc<0.13.0,>=0.12.0 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from awscli==1.6.2->graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.1.0 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from awscli==1.6.2->graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): rsa==3.1.2 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from awscli==1.6.2->graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jmespath==0.5.0 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from botocore<0.74.0,>=0.73.0->awscli==1.6.2->graphlab-create)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1>=0.1.3 in c:\users\a_sk\anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages (from rsa==3.1.2->awscli==1.6.2->graphlab-create)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use anaconda.  If so, then you can just do within conda

```
pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/<YOUREMAILHERE>/<YOUR REGISTRATION CODE HERE- Should look like xxxx-yyyy-zzzz.../GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz
```

Once you do that, you can then do

```
source activate gl-env
jupyter notebook
```

The official docs walk you through this [here](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html):